# CaptureError.CAPTURE_INTERNAL_ERR on Android trying to use capture.captureImage

Tags: multi-device-hybrid-apps

I am trying to write a hybrid app for Android using VS 2013 update 3 and the multi-device hybrid app extension (Cordova v3.5.0). Everything is working well except the Media Capture plugin.  I am calling navigator.device.capture.captureImage(MediaCaptureSuccess, MediaCaptureError, { limit: 3 }) which opens up the camera app. I can take a picture but when I click Ok on the device, my error callback is executed with CaptureError.CAPTURE_INTERNAL_ERR with no other information.  I have tried switching to org.apache.cordova.media-capture@0.3.4 (currently using 0.3.1) but when I try to compile, I get a plugman error when it tries to retrieve it.  I have searched the debug output for clues and the only thing that I found was the following line "Unknown permission android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO in package..." but that seems to be a valid user permission. When I look at capture.java generated by the build, I can see that this error is returned if there is an IOException occurs.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this or what to check next?

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin

Config:

```
<vs:feature>org.apache.cordova.camera@0.3.0</vs:feature>
```

JS:

```
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
        quality: 30,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: true
    });
```

Comment: Looking at the code for this plugin, I can see that it does not have the same problem as the media-capture plugin and will probably work.  The problem is that I also want to be able to take videos which doesn't appear to be supported in the camera plugin.  It appears this plugin will work because it first tries to use the SD card whereas the media-capture plugin does not.  The core issue is that cordova.getActivity().getCacheDir() called from getTempDirectoryPath returns /data/data/com.packagename/cache (internal storage) and the call to cache.mkdirs() fails silently. Permission issue??